# Python - How can I convert S3 folders into JSON hierarchy?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a list using boto3 that contains all the subfolders in my S3 bucket. The list is sorted as below:

```
s3_list = ['a', 'a/a1/a11', 'b', 'b/b1', 'b/b2', 'b/b2/b22']
```

I'm trying to convert this list into JSON hierarchy structure:

```
{
    "root": [
        {
            "name": "a",
            "path": "a",
            "child": [
                {
                    "name": "a1",
                    "path": "a/a1",
                    "child": [
                        {
                            "name": "a11",
                            "path": "a/a1/a11"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "b",
            "path": "b",
            "child": [
                {
                    "name": "b1",
                    "path": "b/b1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "b2",
                    "path": "b/b2",
                    "child": [
                        {
                            "name": "b22",
                            "path": "b/b2/b22"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

Whats the best way/libraries to get this going in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recursion with `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
s3_list = ['a', 'a/a1/a11', 'b', 'b/b1', 'b/b2', 'b/b2/b22']
def to_dict(d, c = []):
   if not d:
      return {}
   _d, r = defaultdict(list), []
   for a, *b in d:
      _d[a].append(b)
   return [{'name':a, 'path':'/'.join(c+[a]), 
           **({} if not (k:=list(filter(None, b))) else  {'children':to_dict(k, c+[a])})} 
           for a, b in _d.items()]
      
result = {'root':to_dict([i.split('/') for i in s3_list])}
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
   "root": [
      {
        "name": "a",
        "path": "a",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "a1",
                "path": "a/a1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "a11",
                        "path": "a/a1/a11"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "b",
        "path": "b",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "b1",
                "path": "b/b1"
            },
            {
                "name": "b2",
                "path": "b/b2",
                "children": [
                     {
                        "name": "b22",
                        "path": "b/b2/b22"
                     } 
                  ]
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
}
```

Comment: @dm2111 Glad to help!

Comment: @dm2111 considerar accept this as answer if it helped you.