# Transform S3 objects into hierarchical (tree) Map in Elixir

Tags: amazon-s3, elixir

I have this task where I need to extract objects from AWS S3 using ExAws and return it to Frontend in a file-tree-like structure.

From the data returned by `ExAws.S3.list_objects("bucket-name", prefix: "folder-path") |> ExAws.request!`

```elixir
%{
  body: %{
    contents: [
      %{key: "file1.svg"},
      %{key: "FolderA/file1.txt"},
      %{key: "FolderA/file2.txt"},
      %{key: "FolderB/Layer1/file1.csv"},
      %{key: "FolderB/Layer1/file2.csv"},
      %{key: "FolderB/Layer1/GroupA/file1.pdf"},
      %{key: "FolderB/Layer1/GroupB/file1.jpg"},
      %{key: "FolderB/Layer2/file1.png"}
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to transform it into something like this map.

```elixir
%{
  "FolderA" => %{
    "file1.txt" => "FolderA/file1.txt",
    "file2.txt" => "FolderA/file2.txt"
  },
  "FolderB" => %{
    "Layer1" => %{
      "GroupA" => %{
        "file1.pdf" => "FolderB/Layer1/GroupA/file1.pdf"
      },
      "GroupB" => %{
        "file1.jpg" => "FolderB/Layer1/GroupB/file1.jpg"
      },
      "file1.csv" => "FolderB/Layer1/file1.csv",
      "file2.csv" => "FolderB/Layer1/file2.csv"
    },
    "Layer2" => %{"file1.png" => "FolderB/Layer2/file1.png"}
  },
  "file1.svg" => "file1.svg"
}
```

I found this npm package, [s3-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-tree) but it does a request per 'folder'. What I need is just pure algorithm.

And these with python: [Python - How can I convert S3 folders into JSON hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67199853/python-how-can-i-convert-s3-folders-into-json-hierarchy), [s3-tree](https://pypi.org/project/s3-tree/). Translating these into elixir would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am here to advertise the most underrated feature of [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir), [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html) behaviour, again.

[`Access.key/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html#key/2) is your friend here.

```elixir
data
|> get_in([:body, :contents, Access.all(), :key])
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn e, acc ->
  put_in(acc, Enum.map(String.split(e, "/"), &Access.key(&1, %{})), e)
end)
```

That’s it.

Comment: Nice. Should have thought of `put_in` instead of writing a custom traverse/merge. `put_in(_brain = %{}, [Access.key(:just, %{}), Access.key(:use, %{})], :put_in)`.

Comment: I didn't expect the code would be this short! Elixir never fails to amaze me! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Nice recursion challenge

I'm not familiar with `ex_aws_s3` so it may be that there is already some functionality there, but here's my attempt:

```elixir
defmodule S3Tree do
  def parse(data) do
    Enum.reduce(data.body.contents, %{}, fn %{key: full_path}, acc ->
      tree = traverse(String.split(full_path, "/"), full_path)
      merge(nil, acc, tree)
    end)
  end

  defp traverse([file], full_path), do: %{file => full_path}
  defp traverse([dir | rest], full_path), do: %{dir => traverse(rest, full_path)}

  defp merge(_key, map1, map2), do: Map.merge(map1, map2, &merge/3)
end
```

---

Usage:

```elixir
data = %{
  body: %{
    contents: [
      %{key: "file1.svg"},
      %{key: "FolderA/file1.txt"},
      %{key: "FolderA/file2.txt"},
      %{key: "FolderB/Layer1/file1.csv"},
      %{key: "FolderB/Layer1/file2.csv"},
      %{key: "FolderB/Layer1/GroupA/file1.pdf"},
      %{key: "FolderB/Layer1/GroupB/file1.jpg"},
      %{key: "FolderB/Layer2/file1.png"}
    ]
  }
}

S3Tree.parse(data)
```

Output:

```elixir
%{
  "FolderA" => %{
    "file1.txt" => "FolderA/file1.txt",
    "file2.txt" => "FolderA/file2.txt"
  },
  "FolderB" => %{
    "Layer1" => %{
      "GroupA" => %{"file1.pdf" => "FolderB/Layer1/GroupA/file1.pdf"},
      "GroupB" => %{"file1.jpg" => "FolderB/Layer1/GroupB/file1.jpg"},
      "file1.csv" => "FolderB/Layer1/file1.csv",
      "file2.csv" => "FolderB/Layer1/file2.csv"
    },
    "Layer2" => %{"file1.png" => "FolderB/Layer2/file1.png"}
  },
  "file1.svg" => "file1.svg"
}
```